# UI thread and AsyncTask synchronization

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How to keep UI thread waiting until i get data from AsyncTask.
i trying to load some information and image from server and display it into textview and imageview respectively. But UI thread access the field before background thread complete its task. So null value is retrieved and application get crashed.

Comment: setText & Image in overriden onPostExecute AsyncTask method , it's called in the UI thread and after the AsyncTask terminates.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the UI in onPostExecute of AsyncTask after doing your background tasks.

For the crash, by accessing the field on UI thread => You need to shift this code also to the onPostExecute method.

So the required data will be available, the field will have a value.
So the crash issue can be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

If you are building an application that basically scrapes the html source and then you manipulate this "string", what you can do is

```
private class Scrapper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    //Get the source here
}
```

Then in the onCreate Method

```
Scrapper scrapper = new Scrapper();
String URLSource = scrapper.execute("url here").get();
//Additional code to manipulate the string
```

However it is generally not recommended to do it this way, since apparently it will put the entire UI Thread on hold and there will be a long delay if the source is large.